# Some Tabler font icons appearing filled

Tags: css, reactjs, icon-fonts

I am trying to use [Tabler icons](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons) in my project React typescript project via `classNames` and for some unknown reasons, some icons appear filled. Please note that my `CSS` skills are not so good.

The library comes with

1. Font icons
2. PNG icons
3. And SVG icons

When I check the font icons[image: Font icons] some icons appear completely filled and because of this when I try to access them like `className="ti ti-discount"` I get icons that look like[image: Font icon when used] while the SVG and PNG counterparts look like [image: SVG and PNG counterparts], am confused, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who sees this question, the poster created a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons/issues/102. According to the project's maintainer, the problem should be solved in the near future (I'd guess early 2021): https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons/pull/92.